# Create Folders Applescript

Tags: applescript, directory, finder

I have an Applescript that I use to create job folders. The Applescript asks for the project name and the location where the folder will be stored. After inputting the job name and folder location, the script creates the main folder and four subfolders.

Now I would like the script to create numbered subfolders within one of the current subfolders, with a prompt that asks the user how many folders to create. Is that possible?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
    set newfoldername to JobName
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Job Materials"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Previews"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"PSDs"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"VX"}
end tell
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"

tell application "Finder"
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:JobName}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Job Materials"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"Previews"}
    set targetFolder to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"PSDs"}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"VX"}
end tell

repeat
    set subCount to text returned of (display dialog "How many subfolders?" default answer 3)
    try
        if subCount ≠ "" then
            subCount as integer
            exit repeat
        end if
    end try
end repeat

repeat with i from 1 to subCount
    tell application "Finder" to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:"Subfolder " & i}
end repeat
```